# Which is right among "a limit" and "limits", followed by "in many areas", in this sentence?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Which is right among the two following sentences?

> My vocabulary, as describing things, has **a disastrous limit in many areas**.
>
> My vocabulary, as describing things, has **disastrous limits in many areas**.

My vocabulary is narrow in every aspect including everyday life, study, politics, society, science. So I came up with the sentences in the yellow box.
But I cannot define whether "limit" has to be singular or plural.

I will appreciate any explanations about this.
Thank you.

Comment: a disastrous limit does not sound good. /My vocabulary is very limited  in many areas/. Very, extremely, terribly, awfully, but not disastrously in this case.

Comment: The slang use of disaster is usually a noun: My vocabulary is a disaster, for instance.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you for your comments. :) Then here, between the verb "have" and the noun "limit"("limits"), which would be the one unfit here? Isn't there no way for "have" to be used like here?

Comment: What you seem to be trying to say is: My vocabulary is very limited in many areas. The slangy way to say it: My vocabulary is a disaster in many areas.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you. But what I am trying to figure out is if the verb "have" can have that sort of meaning. :)

Comment: What sort of meaning? to have limits, no problem. BUT not with the word disastrous. It does not sound good. I already answered your question: is extremely limitED is more idiomatic. Not: my vocabulary HAS LIMITS. An English speaker would most likely not say it as you have formulated it. X has no limits, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If forced to pick between your examples, I would use the plural "limits" even though we're talking about one *limited* subject.

> My vocabulary, when describing things, has disastrous limits.

The final "in many areas" is not necessary when you use the plural.  Since there are many limits, we know that we are talking about various areas where you apply your vocabulary.

However, I would normally say this instead:

> My vocabulary ... **is** disastrously **limited** (in many areas).

Comment: I agree that grammatically disastrously limited is correct but that is something I would never say. It sounds off. Very limited, extremely limited, terribly limited, awfully limited come to mind.